# Listen and cancel notifications of other apps

Tags: ios, swift

On Android, its possible to use [NotificationListenerService.onNotificationPosted](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#onNotificationPosted(android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification)) in combination with [cancelNotification](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService#cancelNotification(java.lang.String)) to listen and cancel notifications programmatically.

Does an API for something like that also exist on iOS?

Comment: Absolutely not. Apps on iOS have no access to notifications of other apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in iOS, you can not access/clear/cancel other application's notifications. For your own application please use following.

```
[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] removeAllDeliveredNotifications];
[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] removeAllPendingNotificationRequests];
```

And also check these. They might help.

1. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649500-removedeliverednotificationswith?language=objc
2. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649502-removealldeliverednotifications?language=objc